# How to create a table in SQL Server database using pandas data frame as a template?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a big Pandas data frame with many columns, say, 25. Now I need to create a table in the SQL Server database to store the content of the data frame. How to avoid manually describing each column parameters in the `CREATE TABLE` command? Is there any solution that uses the data frame columns as a template? Maybe is there some way to run `pandas.to_sql`, but without subsequent insertion of rows?

I don't want to insert the rows into the table using `pandas.to_sql`, because I have too many rows, and this command does not work. I have to export into csv and then use the `bcp` utility.

Comment: You can still use `DataFrame.to_sql`, make use of the `chunksize` parameter which exports the table in chunks to your database. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: you mean that if i write chunksize=0, it will create a table and insert nothing?

Comment: which chunksize value is recommended?

Comment: You can try that, but why would you do that, if your problem is that the data is too big to be exported in one go. Just use `chunksize=10000` for example

Comment: Is there any way to make pandas.to_sql verbose, i.e to report 'processing row 100 from 1000000' etc.?

Comment: Take a look at this you can probably iterate over the chunks and print yourself some indication of how much is processed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas